# Get javascript value to c# string

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

Is it possible to do something like this in c#? The value would be "10/05/2014"

```
string jsValue = javascript("$('#EstimatedStartDate').val()");
```

Comment: show some .aspx code

Comment: What do you expect as output?

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar why would i show aspx code?
i just want to know if there is a c# library for getting a javascript value. btw the value it returns is "10/05/2014". thanks

Comment: If you had a method within scope defined as `string javascript(string param)` then it would compile, but it is not clear what your intended functionality is.

Comment: @VladL the value would be "10/05/2014" thanks

Comment: Javascripts runs in browser and gives you the current value of the DOM element. This of course can not be done in c#. 
But if you only need the value of some element in an Html file there are a lot of ways of doing this in c#.

Comment: @LightWalker22 You are going to have to elaborate, at the moment it seems you want to have a method called `javascript` that returns the string "10/05/2014".

Comment: @DaniCE can you point me one way of doing this? thanks

Comment: Getting the value of the #EstimatedStartDate element in a static html file?

Comment: @BenRobinson yes, i have a datepicker, and i want to get the value.

Comment: C# runs on the server, JavaScript runs on the browser. If you want to get the value of the date picker on the server, it needs to be sent to the server. There are many way to do this, what kind of technology are you using? asp.net web forms, mvc, web api or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you able to clarify what you are trying to do in a bit more detail.

It appears that you are trying to get a string value from javascript (clientside) into a c# variable (serverside).

Is this the case?

If so then you need to expose a serverside method, which accepts a string variable. Then you would need to do an ajax call or a full page postback, which will send the value from clientside to serverside.

This will also depend on the type of environment you are developing for - What are you using? MVC? Do you have a viewmodel you are able to use to pass the value?

But, in short: You are not able to do the line of code you are proposing.

If you are able to provide more information, that would help greatly.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there already exists:
https://github.com/sebastienros/jint

I already used and is like magic.
You can use all js engine with c# and all c# objects under js.
Brilliant.

So.. You want to access browser dom resources on your serverside application?
This isnt possible and i dont know why you want to do this...
You can use ajax to communicate with server...
If you want to use js code under serverside, you can do, but, never will access client dom elements.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

No it is not possible but you can send Jscript variables or objects to server and then retireve their values. Use this :

```
$.ajax{(
    url:"somepage.aspx",
    data:{
        data1 : $("#IdOrClass").val(),
        data2 : "DirectValue",
         }
    type:"get/post",
    success: function (){ alert("success") }
       )}
```

And on server side do this:

```
public void method(string data1, string data2)
{
    var data_1 = data1;
    var data_2 = data2;
}
```

Comment: You're on the right track but this is a very poor example.

Comment: if the example is right then what do you mean by poor example?

Comment: I didn't say the example was correct, i said that it was *on the right track*.

Comment: so what should be the correct example? tell me it will also clear my confusion. Thanks

Comment: If I wanted to answer the question, I would post an answer myself.